# Display NSTimer Count in UILabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, nsstring, int

I'd like to show my countdown for a process to load, and understand that it is disallowed using `ARC` to convert an `int` to an `NSString`. How can I show my `count` within an `NSString`?

```
static int count = 0;
count++;

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(5.0) 
                          target:self 
                          selector:@selector(uploadData) 
                          userInfo:nil 
                          repeats:NO];

if (count <= 5)
{
    ilabel.text = @"Please be patient...";
    NSString *counter = count;
    counterLabel.text = counter;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is:

```
NSString* counter = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", count];
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a typical mistake. I had this, but realized after you posted that my version had paranthesis which were not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1):

```
counterLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
```

Comment: You'll want to pass 'count' in, not 'counter'. would have just editted that for you but I can't edit less than 6 characters. :)